# R extract text from webpage using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to extract two pieces of text from a webpage

**The webpage**

```
page <- read_html("https://www.decathlon.fr/p/kettlebell-12kg/_/R-p-152874")
```

**And the html source code for the portion of text I'd like to extract**

```
<p class="ab-info-stock__text ab-test-info-red">Rupture de stock sur cette taille</p>
```

I tried using `rvest` to extract it, but it doesn't seem to work

```
library(rvest)
element = page %>% html_nodes("ab-info-stock__text ab-test-info-red")
```

Really appreciate some help on where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The site seems to load dynamically. You should thus use `RSelenium` to access the page instead of merely `rvest`.

The following code works for me:

```
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser="firefox")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://www.decathlon.fr/p/kettlebell-12kg/_/R-p-152874")

# scroll down a bit and wait some seconds just to ensure the loading of the page
remDr$executeScript(paste("scroll(0,",i*10000,");")) 
Sys.sleep(5)

# fetch the html code
webpage<- remDr$getPageSource()
webpage<- xml2::read_html(webpage[[1]])

# obtain the text --- use "library(dplyr)" in case you haven't loaded it yet for the pipe (%>%)
stocktext <- webpage %>%
  rvest::html_nodes(".ab-info-stock__text.ab-test-info-red") %>% 
  rvest::html_text()

# exit
remDr$close()
gc()
rD$server$stop()
system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)
```

Comment: Varun, I just tried it out and it actually works. -- What error message do you get? Anyway, I edited the post to make the code more consistent. Please make sure to load at least the library `dplyr` to use the pipe (`%>%`); and make sure to install the `RSelenium` package; and, finally, to use the browser you need (right now, as you see in line 1, it says `browser="firefox"` which is my default browser).